# "docker run" a command located in a mounted volume

Tags: docker

Is there a way to have docker execute a command located in a mounted volume upon container creation?

I have a simple c program located in a directory I'm bind-mounting to the container that outputs the pwd and then runs until killed:

```
flash@dsvm1:~$ ./hello-docker-mount
Hello from /home/flash!
^C
flash@dsvm1:~$ cat hello-docker-mount.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
        char cwd[1024];
        getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
        printf("Hello from %s!\n", cwd);
        for(;;) { sleep(1); }
}
flash@dsvm1:~$ ls /home/flash/hello-docker-mount -al
-rwxrwxr-x 1 flash flash 8728 May 21 22:53 /home/flash/hello-docker-mount
```

However, when I try to "docker run" using this as the command it seems to fail as if the mount occurs after the command is executed:

```
flash@dsvm1:~$ docker run -it --name foo --rm -v /home/flash:/home/flash busybox /home/flash/hello-docker-mount
standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
flash@dsvm1:~$ docker run -it --name foo --rm -v /home/flash:/home/flash -w /home/flash busybox /home/flash/hello-docker-mount
standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
flash@dsvm1:~$ docker run -it --name foo --rm -v /home/flash:/home/flash -w /home/flash busybox ./hello-docker-mount
standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
flash@dsvm1:~$ docker run -it --name foo --rm -v /home/flash:/home/flash -w /home/flash busybox hello-docker-mount
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"hello-docker-mount\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

I also tried with --entrypoint:

```
flash@dsvm1:~$ docker run -it --name foo --rm -v /home/flash:/home/flash --entrypoint /home/flash/hello-docker-mount busybox
standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
flash@dsvm1:~$ docker run -it --name foo --rm -v /home/flash:/home/flash -w /home/flash --entrypoint hello-docker-mount busybox
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"hello-docker-mount\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

If I call an executable that's in the image first, I can see the file:

```
flash@dsvm1:~$ docker run -it --name foo --rm -v /home/flash:/home/flash -w /home/flash busybox ls -l hello-docker-mount
-rwxrwxr-x    1 1003     1003          8728 May 21 22:53 hello-docker-mount
```

I have no control over what users will build in their docker images, so there's no guarantee any particular shell or executable will be available. I need to be able to "docker run -d" their image and ensure it continues to run so that when the user wants to interact with it I can use "docker exec".

Is this possible?

Less desirable, but if the above is not possible - is there an alternative way of adding a file into an existing container image to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has got to do with "how to execute binary in a busybox".

"docker run" mounts the volumes before executing the command.

For example, this works fine with centos:

```
docker run -v /home/chan:/home/chan centos /home/chan/echo.sh
hello world
```

To verify if you can execute the binary in busybox, you can do

```
docker run -it -v /Users/nnatara/Desktop:/home/chan busybox sh
/ # cd /home/chan/
/home/chan # ./echo.sh
hello world
```

In your case, you might encounter issues executing the binary.

- You need to verify if the binary is compiled for the destination
  architecture.
- Check if the required libs are found in the
  environment.

Comment: Thanks Naveen, you pointed me to try a more fully-baked image like centos where it worked as expected, which led me to realize I had not compiled the program statically, pointing to your last bullet point. :) Once compiled correctly, it works in busybox and even in the hello-world image. The "no such file or directory" was just misleading.